# System.String[] will be displayed instead of value on pdfsharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I am using pdfsharp to create pdf. I have got a big text value, so that its not fit into my table column. So that I have tried split function. But the value printed on pdf is `System.String[]`.
Here is my code:

```
private string[] GetLines(string strValue)
{                    
    string[] strLines = strValue.Split('\n');
    int lineLength = strLines.Length;
    return strLines;
}   

DataRow repRow = ReportDS.Rows[rowCount];   
string Result = repRow["result"].ToString();
//result.length is 558
if (Result.Length > 50)
{
    Result = GetLines(Result).ToString(); 
}
```

The value get on Result is `System.String[]`. I need to get values.

Comment: Since result is a single string variable, what do you expect to happen when you split it? you can assign the first result from `GetLines` but then you lose lots of information.

Comment: The single string variable's length is much higher, it cannot fit in my pdf. So I have to split to in an array and assign that value to Result.

Comment: I don't understand what splitting it into an array is achieving? You are still trying to fit it back into the same single string

Comment: In my Result variable I got a very big string with 500 characters. So that I need to split those 500 character into 15 or more blocks. Each block should be displayed on new lines.

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
Result = GetLines(Result).ToString();
```

with

```
Result = string.Join(", ",GetLines(Result));
```

Comment: ~fubo sorry I need to split the values, in your answer the splited values are joined, so that the split function get reversed.

Comment: what do you expect to be the value of "string Result"?

Comment: string result is like this:
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text 
of the printing and typesetting industry.
 Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
 standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
 when an unknown printer took a galley
of type and scrambled it to make a type
 specimen book. It has survived not only
 five centuries.

Comment: but the value will be separated by \n .Because the pdf cannot print if the length is higher.

Comment: I need to add line breaks not to avoid

Comment: to replace space with linebreaks you can do this by Result.Replace(" ", System.Environment.NewLine);

Comment: I think I need to use a for loop to store the array value and assign it to Result.